# What is the difference between remember and remind

Tags: meaning, differences, causative-verbs

Could someone explain the difference between these two words? Here is an example of using each.

- Your hair and eyes **remind** me of your mother.
- I can **remember**    people's faces, but not their names.

Comment: General Reference. **Remind** - [*cause* (someone) to remember someone or something](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+remind&oq=define+remind&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&q=remind&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=YzSIUOFHsozTBYnngTg&ved=0CB8QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=9cc6ce1e3edfb4fe&bpcl=35466521&biw=1084&bih=866)

Comment: Pavel, We'd sure appreciate your support at our proposed sister site for [English Language Learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2); your support there could help make that site a reality.

Comment: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv204.shtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Briefly, *remind* is a **causative** verb, while *remember* is **reflexive**.

The full meaning of *remind* is something like "to cause someone to bring to mind". I.e.:

> Your eyes remind me of your mother = Your eyes cause me to bring your mother to mind.

As demonstrated in the examples above, *remind* is ditransitive, meaning that it has two objects: the first is the person who is caused to remember, the second is the thing which is remembered.

*Remember*, on the other hand, is reflexive, meaning that the subject acts on himself to bring the object to mind:

> I remember your mother = I recall your mother under my own power.

As this illustrates, *remember* is a simple transitive verb that has only one object: the thing that the subject brings into memory.

Both verbs mean the same or nearly the same thing, but they differ in the way that the subject relates to the object.

Comment: i.e. to "remember" is something that you do to yourself; to "remind" is something that you do to someone else. :-)

Comment: @Jay: Not necessarily - don't forget ["remember me to your mother"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22remember+me+to+your+mother%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can **remind** someone else that it is your birthday this weekend, so that they **remember** to buy you a present.

Answer (score 2):

`Remind` can be thought of as `causes someone to remember.`

They are *very* similar in meaning and each is used as part of the definition of the other. They can be used nearly interchangeably without much issue and they both relate to memory obviously, but probably the biggest distinction is that `remind` is capable of being non-specific.

In your example ("Your hair and eyes remind me of your mother"), `remind` does not imply that the child is the mother's twin, but rather evokes the memory of the mother.