# "Try to remember" vs "Try to remind yourself"

Tags: meaning

I've always been confused between these two and not able to understand which one to use and when. Help Please

P.S.-Help me with good tags if possible

Comment: "Try to remind yourself" is technically valid and the two mean roughly the same, but "try to remember" is far more idiomatic.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87988/what-is-the-difference-between-remember-and-remind

Answer (score 1):

Reminding and remembering are related but they don't mean the same thing. To put it simply, to "remind" is **to make or cause** [yourself or someone else] to remember.

The ODO defines the verb "[remember](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/remember)" as:

> 1 [WITH OBJECT] Have in or be able to bring to one’s mind an awareness
> of (someone or something from the past):
> *"I remember the screech of the horn as the car came towards me"*
> *"no one remembered his name"*
>
> 2 [WITH INFINITIVE] Do something that one has undertaken to do or
> that is necessary or advisable:
> *"did you remember to post the letters"*
>
> 2.1 [WITH CLAUSE] Used to emphasize the importance of what is asserted:
> *"you must remember that this is a secret"*

It defines "[remind](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/remind)" as follows:

> [WITH OBJECT]   1 Cause (someone) to remember someone or something:
> *"he would have forgotten my birthday if you hadn’t reminded him"*
>
> [WITH OBJECT AND DIRECT SPEECH]: *"‘You had an accident,’ he reminded
> her"*

If you "remind *yourself*" about something (i.e. without the thought being triggered by an external stimulus), you've simply remembered the thing. In this situation, it's okay to use either word, since the action in both cases is reflexive or internal. However, to remind *someone else* about something is not the same as remembering the thing - you have to construct the sentence differently, e.g.:

*I reminded her to put the cat out*
*I told her to remember to put the cat out*

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you had a meeting tomorrow with your boss: if you set an alarm on your phone, wrote the appointment on your calendar or tie a knot in your handkerchief those will act as **[reminders](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reminder)** and you will have **reminded yourself.** 

If you don't do any other actions but still recall that you have a meeting with the boss, you will **have remembered**.